# why i get true from in_array("a",$array_name)

Tags: php

```
$array_name=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0);
var_dump(in_array("a",$array_name));
```

why I get true?

but i will get false from

```
var_dump(in_array("a",$array_name,true));
```

Comment: https://eval.in/394982 - false

Comment: i know i should get false, but i do get true on my browser

Comment: Are you 100% positive that you're passing the correct array in you REAL code?

Comment: You shouldn't be getting true, not with that exact code.

Comment: i checked many many times

Comment: Post your actual code then, let's see

Comment: I get false as expected

Comment: in first you have in_array with strict = false in second with strict = true

Comment: It returns false, as expected.

Comment: <?php
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0);
var_dump(in_array("aaa",$array));
?>

Comment: last zero - look MarcB's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your exact posted code, you cannot possibly be getting true:

```
php > var_dump(in_array("a", array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)));
bool(false)
```

But if you had a false-y value in the array:

```
php > var_dump(in_array("a", array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)));
                                   ^----- false-y value
bool(true)
php > var_dump(in_array("a", array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), true));
bool(false)
```

Then you would get your expected results. Passing the 3rd `true` argument to `in_array` forces a strict equality test internally, e.g. `===` instead of `==`:

```
php > var_dump("a" == 0, "a" === 0);
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

Comment: thanks a lot! so the 0 is making the difference.

Comment: it's any false-y value, http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have different arguments in `in_array()` function.

in first call you have `strict = false` by default in second it's `true`

This does not means you should get true because `false` is proper returned value

**Edit:**

I thought about code you give in comment and I assume "aaa" is casted to integer 0 then 0 is found in array so it returns true;

Try to remove 0 from your array and it will return false.

`in_array()` has pretty unexpected behavior that is why it is good to use strict option set to true.

```
<?php

 $array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0); 
 $array2 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9); 
 var_dump(in_array("aaa", $array, false));
 var_dump(in_array("aaa", $array2, false));

?>
```

**Output:**

```
bool(true) bool(false)
```

Comment: yes, it looks that way. 0 is causing the difference. but thanks a lot for your answer.